# Sscanf for a string taken by command line

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, c-strings

I have problem with this project, i try to search an answer on forum but i didn't found nothing.

```
struct orario {
int hours;
int minutes;
int seconds;
char *format;
}orario1;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
sscanf(argv[1],"%d:%d:%d %s",&orario1.hours,&orario1.minutes,&orario1.seconds,orario1.format);

printf("%d:%d:%d %s",orario1.hours,orario1.minutes,orario1.seconds,orario1.format);
```

The output is correct for the numerical part but the string(for example AM or PM) is unexpected (null).

I can't recognize my error, can someone find and tell me?!

Thank you.

Comment: You should really check if the user provided one (or more) arguments before using `argv[1]` etc. If no arguments were provided then `argv[1]` will be a null pointers, and `argv[2]` and up will be out of bounds. This check is done by testing that `argc >= 2`.

Comment: Yes i know, i will do it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code has undefined behavior, since `format` is an uninitialized pointer.

Use

```
char format[8];
```

and `%7s`. And check the return value before relying on the variables having values.

Comment: I tried as you say but the result is:
Input: ./project 21:3:2 AM
Output:21:3:2